# Times of code been executed in a nested for loop in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

I am recently reading the book called *Algorithms* by Robert Sedgewick. I came across one piece of code while reading "Analysis of Algorithms". The code is as follow :

```
public static int count(int a[]) {
    int N = a.length;
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++) {
                if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0) {  //here 
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    return cnt
}
```

What I want to know is how many times of the `if`-statement within the `for`-loop been executed. The answer provided by the book is `N(N-1)(N-2)/6`. But I don't know why, could anyone explain.

Comment: did you try inserting a println or two? Did it work?

Comment: It would sound the answer depends on the contents of the array.

Comment: Do you mean how many times is the `if`-statement reached or how many times is the `if`-statement entered? The latter question is not answerable without seeing the input array.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I want to analyze the code instead of really execute it.

Comment: @arshajii I mean the times of the if statement been executed, not neccessarily entered :)

Comment: I think the point of your interest is *finding out why*, and that's where strategically placed printlns, which allow you to trace the program flow, are a huge help.

Comment: First and foremost, you could at least *verify* the statement in the book. What if it's wrong?

Comment: hi @MarkoTopolnik. I verified the expression. it is right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to evaluate the following sum:

[image]

You could do that by hand, but [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5BSum%5BSum%5B1,%20%7Bk,%20j%2b1,%20N-1%7D%5D,%20%7Bj,%20i%2b1,%20N-1%7D%5D,%20%7Bi,%200,%20N-1%7D%5D) is much better at that.

It is not hard to verify that

```
(N-1)(N-2) = N2 - 3N + 2
```

which shows the formula you gave.

---

For the manual analysis:

Start with the inner sum, which is easy:

[image]

Plugging this in the middle sum gives:

[image]

This sum would be easier to evaluate if the dummy variable started from 0 (rather than `i+1`), therefore we apply the dummy transformation `p = j - i - 1`:

[image]

Finally, this must be plugged in the outer sum:

[image]

Comment: thanks Heuster. your answer is correct. I try to evaluate by hand, but did not figured it out.

Comment: @photosynthesis I started too, but it is not trivial. I'll try to update the answer if I have a correct explanation.

Comment: @photosynthesis added the math :)

Answer (score 0):

I've been having a play with this. It seems the question is as much one of Mathematics as it is of computing.

First thing's first. The actual contents of the if statement are a complete red herring as they are dependent on the contents of the array. I have used the first x natural numbers starting from 0 (effectively the index of the array) and as such the if statement never resolves to true.

To test the assertion that the if statement is *accessed* n(n-1)(n-2) times I have changed the code to the following:

```
public class Iteration {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {0,1,2,3,4};

    System.out.println(count(a));



}

public static int count(int a[]) {
    int N = a.length;
    int cnt = 0;
    int access = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        for (int j = i + 1; j < N; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < N; k++) {

                access++;
                System.out.println(access + " " +a[i] + a[j] + a[k]);
                if (a[i] + a[j] + a[k] == 0 ) {  //here 
                    cnt++;
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    return cnt;
}
}
```

The console return from this is the following:

> 1 012 
>   2 013 
>   3 014 
>   4 023 
>   5 024 
>   6 034 
>   7 123 
>   8 124 
>   9 134 
>   10 234 
>   0

That is the count of unique combinations of the integers provided. So I have looked up the formula for unique combinations of three digits from [Maths is fun](http://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations-calculator.html).

A brief synopsis of the '6' in the formula then. As each combination of 3 digits is appearing only once consider how many times you could order 3 digits (lets look at 1, 2 and 3):

> 123 132 213 231 312 321

6 times! but as this combination is appearing only once (123) we divide the total by 6 to find how many are returned. The details on the maths are further described on the link above, including the general solution regardless of the number of integers used, and the size of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The variables i, j, and k are taken from the set {0,1,...,N-1}.  But they're always in order, so the number of possibilities is C(N,3)=N!/((N-3)!3!).